# Получить id элемента GridLayout в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, click

У меня есть каталог объявлений (реализовано в RecycleView), который содержит миниатюры объявлений.

По клику по миниатюре конкретного объявления должна отобразиться карточка объявления.

Получается, что каждый `GridLayout` должен содержать номер объявления, чтобы когда произошло событие `onClick`, я бы мог получить номер объявления и обратиться к серверу для загрузки объявления.

Как правильно это реализовать?

Я пробовал использовать метод `holder.id.setTag(product.getId())`, но получал ошибки. Вот пример кода:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.id.setTag(product.getId())
 }
 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 final GridLayout id;
     ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        id = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.productitem);
     }
}
```

Comment: Что-то вы не то делаете) зачем `GridLayout` в `RecyclerView`? Вообще, правильно работать со списком из адаптера, в элементах которого все должно быть прописано. Тип так: `list.get(position).getId();`

Comment: GridLayout  мне нужен для блочной вёрстки

Comment: а, ок) и все равно непонятно, в чем конкретно у вас сложность. Нужно прописать айди или достать? И куда/откуда?

Comment: Да, достать id элемента, который создаётся программно в адаптере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то чтобы опознать нажатый элемент из динамически добавляемых в `GridLayout` в `RecyclerView`, есть несколько вариантов.

1. Задавайте `tag` (например, номер позиции) при создании `view` и опознавайте по тегу.
2. Считайте созданные элементы отдельно и при создании сразу прописывайте в `onClick` ссылку на функцию, которая в качестве элемента будет принимать номер текущего элемента.
3. Если у вас всё в GL добавляется в строгом порядке, можно найти элемент так: `gd.indexOfChild(clickedChildView)` или обратный (если надо `View`): `gd.getChildAt(index)`
4. Можно сделать отдельный класс, например, `GridFromRecycler`. В адаптере работать с List, а в самом классе прописать логику опознания.

Как-то так.

Comment: Ни как не получается повесть событие onClick на GridLayout.
Мне нужно, чтобы клик обрабатывался по всей области карточки объявления, а не отдельно по изображению, тексту и т.д.

Comment: отключите у всех вью, кроме родительского лэйаута, `clickable` и `focusable` (`false`) и повешайте `onClick` на лэйаут

Comment: Получаю такую ошибку " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method clickProductItem(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.GridLayout with id 'productitem'"
  Код:
       public void clickProductItem(GridLayout view){

        Log.d("test", view.getTag().toString());
         }

Comment: Всё вроде заработало.
Добавил в класс onBindViewHolder метод
 holder.product_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("test", view.getTag().toString());

            }
        });